# Carregar template automaticamente

Tags: php, codeigniter

É possivel programar o codeIgniter para carregar o template automaticamente sem precisar especificar as views a cada chamada no controler?

Exemplo

controller usuario

```
public function listar() {

        $this->load->view('template/header.php');
        $this->load->view('template/navbar.php');
        $this->load->view('template/principal.php');
        $this->load->view('template/footer.php');
}
```

controller vendas

```
public function listar() {

        $this->load->view('template/header.php');
        $this->load->view('template/navbar.php');
        $this->load->view('template/principal.php');
        $this->load->view('template/produtos.php');
        $this->load->view('template/footer.php');
}
```

Percebe-se que existe uma repetição de código a cada chamada. Quero saber se existe uma maneira de chamar as views header, navbar e footer automático.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Usando a biblioteca Most Simple Template Library for CodeIgniter**

A [Most Simple Template Library for CodeIgniter](http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_template) é uma biblioteca realmente bastante simples de se usar. Normalmente, carrega-se as views da seguinte maneira:

```
$this->load->view('conteudo', $data);
```

O código acima quer dizer: carregando a view “conteudo”.

Usando o sistema de templates, a nova maneira é:

```
$this->template->load('template', 'conteudo', $data);
```

Ou seja: carregando a view “conteudo” dentro do template “template”.

**Instalação**

Instale o sistema de template através destes passos simples:

1. Baixe o arquivo [ci_template_library.zip](http://maestric.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=&cache=cache&media=php:ci_template_library3.zip);
2. Coloque o arquivo Template.php em ***application/libraries***;
3. Faça o autoload da biblioteca no arquivo ***application/config/autoload.php*:** `$autoload['libraries'] = array('template');`;

**Uso da Most Simple Template Library**

Primeiramente, é preciso criar o template que será usado. Por exemplo:

*application/views/template.php*:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="contents"><?php echo $contents ?></div>
        <footer>Copyleft</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Atenção ao fato de que a view (com os dados) sempre será enxertada no local em que, no template, tiver a variável `$contents` (No exemplo, dentro de `<?php echo $contents ?>`).

Peguemos o exemplo de uma view “conteudo”:

*application/views/conteudo.php*:

```
<header><h1>Nome do site</h1></header>
<p>Algum par&aacute;grafo com conte&uacute;dos.</p>
```

E, finalmente, no ponto do controller em que normalmente carregamos a view, agora carregamos o template, usando sua sintaxe própria:

```
$this->template->load('template', 'conteudo');
```

Answer (score 5):

Tambem fiz de outra maneira muito simples utilizando um Helper:

**template_helper.php**

```
<?php

function teste($pagina){
    $ci = get_instance();

    $ci->load->view('admin/static/header');
    $ci->load->view($pagina);
    $ci->load->view('admin/static/footer');
}
```

**Controller que estou usando**

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->helper('template');
            teste('admin/dashboard');
        }

}
```

Passo a pagina que quero renderizar como parâmetro da função do Helper: `'admin/dashboard'`

Answer (score 1):

Sem uso de bibliotecas de terceiros também é possível criar um sistema de templates facilmente. Fiz da seguinte forma:

Primeiro é necessário definir um controller-base no arquivo **/Application/Core/MY_Controller.php**. Nesse arquivo vou definir um método chamado `view()`.

```
 <?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('Acesso Negado');

 class BaseController extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($arquivo, $titulo, $dados = NULL) {
      $dados = ["arquivo" => $arquivo,
                "titulo" => $titulo,
                "dados" => $dados
              ];

      $this->load->view("template.php", $dados);
    }
 }

 ?>
```

Criar o arquivo template.php na pasta **/Application/Views/**

```
<html>
  <head>.....</head>
  <body>
     <?php $this->load->view("header.php"); ?>

     <div class="main container">

       <?php
           $this->load->view($arquivo, $dados);
         ?>
    </div>

     <?php $this->load->view("footer.php"); ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Exemplo de utilização

```
class Cursos extends BaseController {

  public function index() {
      $this->load->model("CursoModel", "model");
      $dados = ["cursos" => $this->model->listar()];
      $this->view("cursos/cursos.php", "Listagem de Cursos", $dados);
  }
}
```