# Carregando mútiplas VIEWS no CodeIniter

Tags: codeigniter, view

Como o Cabeçalho e o Rodapé serão o mesmo em todas as páginas, existe alguma desvantagem em chamá-las no mesmo `Controller`?

EX:

```
$this->load->view('v_header', $variaveis);
$this->load->view('v_index', $variaveis);
$this->load->view('v_footer', $variaveis);
```

Já que algumas páginas terão arquivos `JavaScript` que outras não precisam, inserir todos no arquivo de rodapé deixariam a aplicação mais lenta?

Comment: Para carregamento por demanda, eu tenho um `helper` que só carrega os scripts usados no método ativo. Vale a pena fazer outra pergunta...

Comment: Use esse [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41272/54880) para sanar a primeira dúvida, em relação ao `JAVASCRIPT` tudo depende de um contexto maior, talvez trabalhar com javascript compactados (`min.js`) pode ser uma boa ... tudo depende... fica um pouco dificil sem ver o que acontece sem teste ... etc ...