# AdminLTE2 + Fullcalendar - problema ao integrar ambos

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, fullcalendar

Boa tarde galera tudo bem? 
Então estou desenvolvendo um pequeno sistema com o Codeigniter, e para isso estou utilizando o template [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html), e agora estou criando a parte de calendário+agenda e para isso estou utilizando [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)

```
$this->template->set('title', 'Lista de Clientes');
$data['clientes'] = $this->model->listar();
$this->template->load('layout', 'clientes_lista.phtml', $data);
```

Utilizando o Template desta forma já conseguir gerar diversas views mas ao tentar utilizar com o Fullcalendar ele desconfigura o template e não exibe o calendário como vou mostrar abaixo

Template funcionando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Template com o Fullcalendar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O estranho é que se carregar a view do meu calendário de maneira normal ele abre sem problemas 
    $this->load->view('calendar_v.php'); meu calendário

Utilizando apenas a view do fullcalendar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da view do calendário:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <link href=' <?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/calendar/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/calendar/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print'>
        <script src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/calendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/calendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/calendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>calendar2/getEvents', function(data){
                    // Console.log para evitar transtornos
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                        },
                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                        editable: true,
                        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                        events: $.parseJSON(data)
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 40px 10px;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            #calendar {
                max-width: 800px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id='calendar'></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Devido a minha inexperiência não consigo encontrar o porque desse comportamento, não sei se o AdminLTE tem alguma incompatibilidade como script ou algo assim, também não sei se por em ambas as views(template e calendário) possuírem a tag  pode gerar algum problema, emfim desde já agradeço.

Edit:
dando uma olha no console encontrei o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Use `<?php echo base_url('assets/calendar/fullcalendar.min.css'); ?>`. É o modo correto.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas continuou com o mesmo problema

Comment: O comentário não foi com a intenção de resolver o problema, foi só pra vc saber que esse método `base_url()` tem que ser usado da forma correta ;)

Comment: ha assim sim, obrigado.

Comment: Você testou se os links estão funcionando corretamente? Qual sua base_url()? Está correta? Verifique se o browser está trazendo os arquivos corretamente. Verifique também se os dados estão sendo trazidos corretamente em `$.post()`

Comment: Encontrei um erro dando uma olha no console, editei a pergunta.

Comment: Tem como copiar o texto do erro? Eu não consigo abrir a imagem.

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, vc tem duas views. Uma é o template, e a outra carrega o calendário. _Vc está tentando carregar o calendário dentro do template, mas fica em branco_. Se for isso, edite a pergunta **e mostre como esse template carrega essa view**. Está confuso. Se o que eu percebi está correto, vc está tentando carregar uma página HTML inteira dentro de outra página HTML, e essa requisição `$.post` não roda se vc fizer isso.

Comment: @ShutUpMagda Ele tem, **provavelmente**, um banco de dados com eventos e está tentando carregar esses eventos por meio do post no calendário - Full Calendar. Não há problema de compatibilidade com a dashboard *AdminLTE*, porque conforme [essa página](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/pages/calendar.html), eles estão integrados. Pode ser um problema com formato da data (*data é sempre um problema*).

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway, sim, sim. O que está confuso é a view que mostra o calendário de eventos. Aparentemente, ele não está usando um template (ou não usa da forma correta), e acha que precisa criar um `<head>` dentro da view para poder usar o _Fullcalendar_. Nesse caso, ele precisa mostrar o método que chama esse calendário (que deve ser `Agenda()`) pra gente saber se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Acredito ter encontrado o problema em ambos os documentos estou carregando o javascript se eu retirar do template ele abre o calendário dentro da área do template um pouco desconfigurado apenas mas abre

Comment: Remova da view, não do template. O template deve ser o mesmo para todas as views. Se ele for o mesmo para todas, não há necessidade de recarregar scripts nelas.

Comment: Problema que se  eu retiro da view ele não reconhece o script

Comment: Então você está fazendo errado. Não há margem pra essa necessidade de carregar scripts na view. No _MVC CodeIgniter_ usando _template_ o trabalho da view não é esse. Carrega-se o `<head>` na view apenas quando não se usa _template_. OU vc não está usando _template_, ou está usando de forma equivocada. Lembre-se: no _CodeIgniter_, quando vc fala "_template_", está querendo dizer isso [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41226/42307).