# Resgatar dados do controller em várias views

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou desenvolvendo um site em *CodeIgniter* no qual todas as páginas têm que possuir um *footer* dinâmico com dados vindo do banco.

Carreguei a *view footer* (criei um *controller footer*) no *controller* inicial que carrega um *layout* padrão (que vai em todas as páginas) e o conteúdo da *view* inicial e deu certo, mas nas outras páginas não aparece.

Gostaria, se possível, de sugestões de como fazer isso, de como passar dados vindo de um *controller* para várias *views*.

Função index do controller inicial.

```
    public function index()
{

    ################### DESTAQUE ########################
    //$sql2['not_in']       =   array('field'   => 'id',    'search'    =>  $data['destaque1'][0]['id']);
    $sql1['not_secure']     =   FALSE;
    $sql1['where']          =   array(
        'status'    =>  1,  
        "arquivo != " => "''");
    //$sql1['where']            =   array('status'  =>  1,      'destaque'  =>  1,  "arquivo != " => "''", 'data_pub <= ' => "'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'");
    $sql1['order']          =   array(
            'field' =>  'ci_vitrines.data',
            'hang'  =>  'DESC'
    );
    $sql1['limit']          =   3;
    // core/MY_Controller.php
    $data['vitrines']       =   $this->get_data('vitrines', NULL, $sql1);


    ################### UNIDADES ########################

    $sql2['where']          =   array(
            'status'    =>  1,
            'tipo'      =>  1
    );

    $sql2['order']          =   array(
            'field'     =>  'data',
            'hang'      =>  'DESC'
    );

    $sql2['limit']          =   14;

    $data['unidades']       =   $this->get_data('unidades', NULL, $sql2);

    ################### FRASES ASSOCIE-SE #######################

    $sql3['where']          =   array(
            'status'    =>  1
    );

    $sql3['order']          =   array(
            'field'     =>  'data',
            'hang'      =>  'DESC'
    );

    $sql3['limit']          =   4;

    $data['frases']         =   $this->get_data('frases', NULL, $sql3);

    ################### ULTIMAS NOTICIAS ########################
        /*$sql2['where']            =   array(
                'ci_noticias.status'    =>  1,
                'ci_noticias.destaque'  =>  2
        );
        $sql2['order']          =   array(
                'field' =>  'ci_noticias.data',
                'hang'  =>  'DESC'
        );
        $sql2['limit']          =   5;
        // core/MY_Controller.php
        $data['last_noticias']  =   $this->get_data('noticias', NULL,   $sql2);*/


    $this->site_template_load('layout', $this->_namemodel, $data);

}
```

Função site_template_load

```
    public function site_template_load($template = '', $view = '', $view_data = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    if($this->check_painel() === FALSE) // SITE
    {
        if(isset($_GET['versaoclassica'])) session("versaoclassica", 1);
        $viewatual = ($this->agent->is_mobile() && !session("versaoclassica")) ? "site" : "site";

        if(file_exists(APPPATH.'views/'.$viewatual.'/' . $template . '.php'))
        {
            $path_template = $viewatual.'/' . $template;
        }
        else
        {
            $path_template = 'demo/' . $template;
        }

        if(file_exists(APPPATH.'views/'.$viewatual.'/' . $view . '.php'))
        {
            $path_views = $viewatual.'/' . $view;
        }
        elseif(file_exists(APPPATH.'views/demo/' . $view . '.php'))
        {
            $path_views = 'demo/' . $view;
        }
        else
        {
            show_404();
        }
    }

    $this->template_set('contents', $this->load->view($path_views, $view_data, TRUE));
    return $this->load->view($path_template, $this->template_data, $return);
}
```

Comment: O que você já tentou? Recebeu alguma mensagem de erro? Se possível, poste um trecho do código que você acredita ser a fonte do problema

Comment: Se vc quer que o rodapé seja dinâmico e mude a depender da _VIEW_ que é chamada isso não é trabalho para um _controller_, e sim pra um _helper_.

Comment: A propósito, se vc mostrar como está fazendo isso vai ajudar a ter ideias de como melhorar seu código ;)

Comment: Na verdade comecei a testar opções agora. Tenho um layout padrão, que é carregado em todas as páginas, e a interna de cada página é montada dependendo do que vai mostrar. Tentei fazer usando include no layout, na na view inicial mostrou os dados, mas nas outras não. O valor de retorno é null.

Comment: Como seria feita isso em um helper? Não precisa de código em si, estou mais a procura de uma ideia de como fazer isso e porque na view inicial o conteudo foi carregado, e nas outras não, apesar de todas as view usarem o mesmo arquivo de layout.

Comment: Eu sei que vc está procurando o conceito, mas entenda: se eu vir o seu código saberei como vc está chamando esse _layout_ padrão; se vc está usando carregamento direto ou por _template_, etc. Só de ouvir vc falar, fica difícil, porque existem inúmeras possibilidades, compreende? O certo é que a sua solução passa por _helper_, só me resta saber como adaptar no seu modo de carregar esse _layout_.

Comment: Mostre o _controller_ que carrega as _views_ com esse _layout_, aí a resposta vem rápido ;)

Comment: Vou editar a resposta com os códigos.

Comment: `template_set()` e `site_template_load()` são métodos seus, certo? Você os criou para tentar carregar o _layout_ padrão em todas as _views_, correto?

Comment: São metodos meus. Na verdade eles funcionam perfeitamente. A unica questão seria a passagem dos parâmetros para todas as views, porque se fosse estático, não teria problema.

Comment: Pessoalmente, acho que vc não precisa inventar um mecanismo pra carregar _views_. Já existe biblioteca pra isso [veja aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41226/42307). Vou tentar te dar uma resposta com _helper_, mas não consegui compreender esse seu método de carregamento.

Comment: Interessante essa biblioteca, vou dar uma olhada melhor depois. Na verdade esses métodos já existiam e eram usados aqui na empresa, só passei a usar também quando fui contratado. Fico no aguardo da sua resposta e obrigado pela atenção.