# Qual a melhor forma para chamar arquivos?

Tags: codeigniter, mvc, include

Bom, eu uso codeigniter (mas não especificamente nele, qualquer um que seja MVC). Queria saber qual a melhor forma de chamar meus arquivos, css, js, fonts, etc. Creio eu que a melhor forma é chamar no método do controller, mas vamos supor que para cada página(método) eu deseje usar um certo plugin código Js mas na outra não, como eu faria?

Um dia eu fiz algumas condicionais (php), verificando se a URI (nome do controller) for tal carregue tal arquivo(css, js, etc), e isso no footer.php do meu template. No caso essa seria a melhor alternativa?

Obrigado!

Comment: Você pode fazer uma estrutura de templates, onde você teria um template base (menu, footer e os imports necessários) e que os outros fizessem o include dele e de qualquer outros imports adicionais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua ideia básica de condicionar pelo nome do *controller* é correta (na minha opinião), mas a execução pode ser melhorada. Use *file_helper.php* pra ajudar a executar a tarefa. É relativamente simples: estenda o *helper* na forma indicada na [documentação](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html?highlight=extending#extending-helpers):

Crie *MY_file_helper.php* em *application/helpers/* e ponha o seguinte lá dentro:

```
if(!function_exists('js_loader')){

/**
* Carrega os scripts por demanda, a depender do controller ativo e do 
* diretorio definido
* @return string
*/
function js_loader() {
    //Captura a instancia do CI
    $ci = & get_instance();
    //Captura o controller ativo
    $controller = $ci->router->fetch_class();
    //Declara o diretorio onde estao os scripts do $controller. 
    //Este diretorio precisa estar acessivel ao navegador
    $jsdir = "assets/js/$controller/";
    //Checagem do $jsdir
    if(file_exists($jsdir)){
        $DirectoryIterator = new DirectoryIterator($jsdir);
        echo "<!--Scripts do controller $controller-->\n";
        foreach ($DirectoryIterator as $entry) {
            //Carrega apenas arquivos (exclui diretorios...)
            if ($entry->isFile()) {
                //Carrega apenas arquivos '.js'
                if (in_array($entry->getExtension(), ['js'])) {
                    $file = base_url($jsdir.$entry->getFilename());
                    echo "<script src='$file' charset='UTF-8'></script>\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Carregue o *helper* na instância do *CodeIgniter* (ou use [autoload](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html)) e chame a função em qualquer parte da *view*:

```
<?php $this->load->helper('file'); ?>
 <html>
  <body>
   <?= js_loader() ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basicamente: todos os scripts .js que estiverem dentro de `"assets/js/$controller/"` serão carregados quando `$controller` estiver ativo.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor prática seria deixar as chamadas de recursos na View, pois é a ela que eles irão servir.

Assim como o @leonardopessoa comentou na sua pergunta, você pode criar templates que forneçam partes comuns ao template principal, por exemplo:

application/views/header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World - Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="folha_de_estilo_main_para_todos.css">
</head>
<body>
```

applications/views/footer.php

```
    <script src="script_main_para_todos.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

applications/views/page_personal.php

```
<p>
    Hello world - Template do método personal!
</p>
```

applications/views/page_contact.php

```
<p>
    Hello again, world - Template do método contact!
</p>
<script src="script_customizado_apenas_para_este_template.js"></script>
```

applications/controllers/pages.php

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
 
public function index() 
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('page_personal');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}

public function contact() 
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('page_contact');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

Bom, acredito que não há uma forma ideal, mas na minha opinião, esta seria a melhor forma de organizar os recursos em uma aplicação MVC, principalmente, aplicações com CodeIgniter, que não fornece helpers tão legais assim para se fazer isso.

> Utilizei trechos de código do link a seguir para escrever está resposta, nele, poderá ser encontrada uma outra forma de implementar templates no CI, mas não achei nada interessante: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-views-templating-in-codeigniter--net-25648

Comment: Resposta apressada. Isso não é estrutura de _templates_ no _CodeIgniter_. Estrutura de templates é [isso aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41226/42307). Vc deu uma referência na sua resposta mas não a seguiu.

Comment: Bom, sem utilizar recursos extras, é sim uma estrutura de template, não se prenda a nomes, lendo a documentação do CI, não há nada para trabalhar com templates dessa forma e é algo bem diferente.

Comment: Não, não é. E vc não usou a documentação do _CI_ como referência. E mesmo que vc usasse a [referência do CI](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html?highlight=template), sua resposta ainda seria carregamento de várias _views_, e não uso de _template_. Vc leu a referência que indicou? Leia a parte **"Templating in CodeIgniter"**. OBS: a documentação oficial tem sim uma forma de se trabalhar com _templates_ ;)

Comment: ahuaha... cara... Na boa, se quer tanto ajudar com a melhor resposta, posta ela aqui. Se ele aplicar o que eu passei, tenho certeza que irá obter o resultado esperado e não tão distante do que é aplicado em outros frameworks, você está com a palavrinha "Template" na cabeça e está atrapalhando. Quer fazer as coisas da forma certa? Use um framework maduro e que não invente tanta moda quanto o CI. Sério, aquela lib é uma alternativa melhor? E se existe essa tal documentação secreta sobre algo que o CI não tem suporte, poxa vida, posta aqui. AJUDE A COMUNIDADE

Comment: só pra constar: foi vc que deu a referência, e a documentação "secreta" está no comentário.

Comment: Documentação do CI sobre Template (único trecho): The Template Parser Class can perform simple text substitution for pseudo-variables contained within your view files. It can parse simple variables or variable tag pairs.

Ultima linha do método load da lib de template: $this->ci->load->view('templates/'.$tpl_name, $data);

Ou seja, é a mesma coisa. Obrigado pelas opiniões na resposta, mas foram desnecessárias.

Comment: Foram úteis para provar no mínimo uma coisa: vc não conhece o que está afirmando na sua resposta. Note que, de acordo com a documentação, se em *blog_template.php* nosso amiguinho declarar as variáveis certas, é só chamar os arquivos correspondentes no _array_ `$data` em `$this->parser->parse('blog_template', $data);`, e não ficar chamando um monte de _views_ ao mesmo tempo. Tradução: **não é a mesma coisa** ;)

Comment: Por isso que o stack não recomenda "discussões", mas enfim, @AdrianoFernandes eu faço isso mesmo o que você fez no seu controller, header depois page depois o footer, porém minhas chamadas para JS ficavam tudo no footer, e até quando eu não precisava do código, lá estava aquele montão de <script src>, entende!? ShutUpMagda Eu já fiz assim também, um layout (view) onde tem as variaveis header e footer, ambos eram chamados na view pela variavel que foi passada no controller e não uma monte de views sendo chamadas no controller, mas mesmo assim obrigados a todos!

Comment: Repare bem que em nenhum momento eu disse que a resposta dele não servia, só disse que ele confundiu os conceitos. É relativamente fácil carregar apenas os métodos que vc definir pra um _controller_. Basta usar um _helper_. Vou dar uma resposta aqui depois...