# Criar componentes html CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Estou usando `CodeIgniter` e não sei como criar componentes para embutir nas minhas *views*. Acho que devo criar meus componentes usando *templates*, correto? Tenho muitos códigos repetidos nas *views* mas vi que, usando *parser*, o consumo de recursos no servidor aumenta muito. O que posso fazer para aumentar a reutilização de código no meu projeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, usar *templates* é bom, e há uma resposta excelente [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41226/42307). Mas o uso de *templates* pras *views* não implementa propriamente componentes `HTML`. Siga a orientação na indicação e adicione o mecanismo de *templates*. Vai ajudar a incrementar a reutilização de código, principalmente se vc tem seções diferentes dentro do sistema.

**Componentes criados com helpers**

Para implementar componentes, sugiro usar um `helper`. Particularmente, o [HTML Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html). Carregue-o na aplicação usando o [Autoload](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html?highlight=autoload#auto-loading-resources).

Dentro de `application/config/autoload.php`, procure por `$autoload['helper']` e acrescente o `helper html` na lista:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('html');
```

[Crie/extenda](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html?highlight=extending#extending-helpers) `application/helpers/MY_html_helper.php` e insira o seguinte:

```
if( ! function_exists('bootstrap_alert')){

    function bootstrap_alert($class=null, $msg=null){
        $ci = & get_instance();
        echo '<div class="alert alert-'.$class.' alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
        echo '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"';
        echo 'aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
        echo $msg;
        echo '</div>';
    }

}
```

Pronto. Com a *function* `bootstrap_alert()` eu criei um componente [Alert](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#alerts) da biblioteca CSS Bootstrap v3.3.7. Agora é só chamar `bootstrap_alert()` em qualquer *view* passando a `$msg` e a `$class` CSS desejada que essa estrutura será mostrada.

Isso vale para, literalmente, qualquer tipo de componente `HTML` que vc precisar criar.

**Componentes a partir de arquivos físicos**

Pode ser necessário carregar componentes a partir de modelos gravados no servidor. Modais, por exemplo, podem ser carregados para o documento `HTML` e manipulados com `JavaScript` para criar interações com o usuário. Segue a função:

```
if( ! function_exists('load_modal')){

    /**
     * Carrega conteudo de arquivos no corpo do documento HTML;
     * @return void
     */
    function load_modal() {
        $path = APPPATH . "views/modal/";
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            $iteractor = new DirectoryIterator($path);
            foreach ($iteractor as $entry) {
                if ($entry->isFile()) {
                    $exts = ['php'];
                    if (in_array($entry->getExtension(), $exts)) {
                        include_once($path.$entry->getFilename());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basicamente, todos os arquivos *.php* que vc salvar dentro do diretório `$path` serão carregados para o `HTML` no local em que a *function* `load_modal()` for chamada (o que pode ser imediatamente após `<body>`, por exemplo). Sabendo disso, dentro de `$path`, salve o arquivo *modal.php*:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$ci = & get_instance();
?>
<!-- modal_alert-->
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" id="modal_alert" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal_alert_label">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?= base_url('users/modal_alert') ?>">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal_alert_label">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
                        Aviso
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class='alert' role='alert'>
                        <center>
                            <p class='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign'></p>
                            <br>
                            <h3><b id="modal_alert_content"></b></h3>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" id="modal_alert_cancel_button">
                        Fechar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- modal_alert-->
```

Escolhi salvar como `.php` por que posso precisar/querer que esse modal imprima algum item de configuração, algum dado do banco, ou qualquer outra coisa (no caso, usei `base_url('users/modal_alert')` na `action` do formulário). Mas isso não é obrigatório, como você pôde ver na função acima.

Isso vale para, literalmente, qualquer tipo de componente `HTML` que vc precisar criar a partir de arquivos pré-formatados.

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado, irei fazer um teste.

Comment: Perfeito!, funcionou!, obrigado...